# Javascript: Expected Identifier

Tags: javascript

I am creating an HTML document and using javascript to create an image element.
Here is my code (create is already defined):

```
create=document.createElement("img");
create.src = 'data/1.png';
create.alt = 'image1';
create.style.magin = '1px';
eval("create.id = 'image" + count + "'");
create.class = 'block'; // line that breaks the code
document.body.appendChild(create);
```

I don't know what's going wrong here, but it's probably something obvious. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Variable `count` isn't defined.

Comment: Also use `create.classList.add('block');` to add the class to the element.

Comment: This code works. So, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code working with the variable `count` defined, an example image and the correct way to add a class to the element:

```js
var count = 1;
create=document.createElement("img");
create.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'; // 'data/1.png';
create.alt = 'image1';
create.style.magin = '1px';
eval("create.id = 'image" + count + "'");
create.classList.add('block');
document.body.appendChild(create);
```

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer, no clue why though.

Comment: no clue why too

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wasn't anything hard.

Answer (score 0):

As no necessity for eval and you can use classList for add  a class.

```js
for(var count = 1; count < 10; count++){ 
  create=document.createElement("img");
  create.src = 'data/1.png';
  create.alt = 'image' + count;
  create.style.magin = '1px';
  create.id = 'image' + count; 
  create.classList.add('block');
  document.body.appendChild(create);
}
```

You also can use `create.style.display = 'block';` if you want just add a style.

More examples how set attributes and styles [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)